# Reporting Services Line Chart - let users choose lines

Tags: reporting-services, linechart

I have a line chart with four lines:

- Total
- A
- B
- C

It is a only a limited number of lines, and I want to allow the user to specify via input parameters what lines to show (i.e. `ShowTotal`, `ShowA`, `ShowB`, `ShowC` booleans).

Can it be done, and how?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mostly there.

Create Boolean Parameters for each line. 
Then use filters or set lines hidden (depending on how you data is coming in) using those parameters.